# How to connect pc speaker with 12v output in car without noise and voltage issues

Tags: voltage, ac, speakers

I am having a pc speaker which i need to connect with 12v output in my car.
I have to exclude my adaptor section and directly connect the power from the 12v supply to speaker power input.

**Car:**

Chevrolet Sail UVA

Output : 12V DC (not sure about the amp. I think it residing between 10 to 15 amps. The voltage also vary according to the battery charging. I think it residing between 10 to 14 volts)

**Speaker:**

[Creative Inspire M2600](http://tech.firstpost.com/product/speakers/inspire-m2600-specification-92262.html)

adapter output : 12v ~ 2.9A AC

Here the main problems are voltage variation and the type of supply(AC/DC). Do we need to convert DC to AC for the power input. And also do we need a voltage protection for the input.

Please Let me know the simplest way to connect this. Is there any practical chalenges.

Do we need to consider the adapter voltage

> 1.414 times 12 = 17V

Comment: If you have the time and skill open the speaker and take a photo of the top and bottom of the circuit board.  Folk here will be able to give a lot more advice if they know how the unit is set up.  Some equipment will not care if AC or DC, some will only work with one, some with the other.  There is a good chance it can work with car power but you may find engine (alternator) noise audible and other minor loss of fidelity.

Comment: can this noise avoided by connecting 1000uf capacitor parallel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Comment: @Passerby not exacly... here we have a   sound system may afeect noise also..

Comment: Open your speaker and I can almost guarantee you it's a diode bridge and a capacitor straight at the "AC" input. If so, you can feed it DC and it will most likely run anyway albeit you can't play as loud.

Comment: @winny why the loudness decreases. How much % it decrease?

Comment: @KIRANKJ Not overall, but your rail voltage will go from 17 V to ~13 V so the maximum power/SPL will be 2.33 dB less before clipping. Play less loud than maximum and you will expereience no difference.

Comment: I tried with the answer given by Bianca. I connected my sound system directly to the 12v supply in my car. It working fine now. I just played once. In long run i dont know what will happen. I will update you within one week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest way, just get this kind of cable, and you're done - zero challenge.

[image]

Comment: I know. I've done this before, trust me. Even you will no need to pay any attention regarding voltage polarity.  12 volt will be cut about 0.8 V by the rectifier inside. That woofer box is not using any voltage regulator. Just a bridge + caps. You won't be noticed any changes on the sound by your bare ears.

Comment: comment above me removed. my answer down voted. i also start a thread yesterday, no any answer, bombard with down vote... seems this electronics discussion board is FULL OF DOWN VOTER ADDICT.

Comment: You are correct on both both your conclusions.

Comment: I tried with the answer given by Bianca. I connected my sound system directly to the 12v supply in my car. It working fine now. I just played once. In long run i dont know what will happen. I will update you within one week.                                                          @Bianca:- I will respond to your answer within one week

Comment: @Bianca I am having dvd player with output 40-40. I need to connect the above mentioned speaker (creative inspire M2600) to the dvd output. Please help